How to flag mass post approval in Staging Ground
I was looking at the review history of Staging Ground and found someone who approved about 50 posts within minutes.

Here is some of the approved questions:

Tabulator with multiple tables in a single page is sharing column calculations from one table to all tables, and more

React Native: How do I render a component on my previous page when I pressed on my button in the next page?

SoftProdigy System Solutions


The first one lacks proper formatting, the second lacks relevant information and the last one is literally ads.
What can I do to report this behavior?

Just approving the third post you linked is probably worth reporting already

@nalka the question was how to report it, not if to report it. Everything to do with the staging ground is just vague to me, but since the posts are already migrated... I guess a custom mod flag on any of them?

Related: Should I not flag users with very questionable SG reviews?

@chivracq the user here was suspended for voting irregularities (presumably off the back of the flag I raised, and maybe others). They've also just lost over 1.3k in reputation for delete user accounts. From their account, i don't think this is the first time they've committed voting fraud. Robo-Reviewing doesn't end up with suspensions very often; normally just a "ban" from the review queues.

As for loss of badges, unfortunately it's rare that they are removed. It would be nice if they were, due to the gamification that [so] has made of things like the review queues and SG.

@ThomA Yeah-yeah, I had seen the "for voting irregularities" on the User's Profile, but thought that Mods only have a limited set of Suspension Reasons to choose from ('Voting irregularities', 'Cool down period', etc...) and probably none specific to the 'SG' and they therefore had chosen one of the Reasons that would be the closest... And I couldn't check their Rep anymore as they were already at 1-Rep from being suspended... But that's already 2 Users doing the same damage to the 'SG' in less than 24h... Some Rate-Limit should be implemented, Minimum 30 sec between 2 Approvals in the 'SG'.

@chivracq I don't think I agree with the rate limiting. If it was in place, would we have still noticed these robo-reviews? I'd much prefer requiring at least 2 approvals (just like for duplicate/off-topic) before they leave SG. This way you could notice someone approved stuff that was obviously not to approve (like OP's third linked question) instead of having the post leave SG and likely nobody checking it in SG again

@nalka "If it was in place, would we have still noticed these robo-reviews?" Well, I did, reason I came to 'Meta', thinking it was a "plague" as I had already flagged another User 12h before, doing exactly the same thing, (that nobody else had noticed I suppose), and for both the "quick rate" was just "a quick and easy confirmation" for me... In "the meantime" 50 Posts got sent to 'Main' x2 in 5 min each, and those 100 (and probably more!) Posts "escaped from 'SG'" are now creating this kind of discussions on 'Meta' about the use of 'SG'...

You can flag these posts for moderator attention just like you can do it on the main site.
To do this, Staging Ground questions have a "Flag" button below the tag list.

You can then select "In need of moderator attention" and explain what issue you are seeing. If you need to provide many Staging Ground question links as evidence, you can use a markdown link ([text](link here)) with /q/<question id> where you replace <question id> with the actual question ID which you can get from the post URL (https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/<question id>).

As mentioned in the comments by blackgreen, you would ideally flag a post written by the reviewer if this is possible.

the best thing to do is to flag a post of the reviewer, not an SG post they reviewed. This way moderators can find the relevant flag history from the reviewer's profile.


Ah yes. So even though the posts have already been migrated, you can still flag the original staging ground posts. I guess that makes more sense as that would put it under the eyes of the people who specifically moderate staging ground stuff.

Yes, the flag button is available for all Staging Ground posts including deleted and published ones. But it would (in principle) also be possible to flag the published post and explain it being about the Staging Ground graduation.

@dan1st sounds reasonable, but I still think flagging question should be for the question only.

@LãNgọcHải What do you mean with "for the question only"? For custom flags, it doesn't have to be that specific post that is the problem but also something about a user or similar. For that reason, there is also the ability to flag one's own posts even without the flagging privilege.

@dan1st I mean I want to use question flag to explain about question only instead of using it as a way to also report a user (that's just my opinion). But yeah, your explaination is reasonable so I marked as answer

@LãNgọcHải the only way we have to raise flags is to raise it on a post (a different way would need us to wait for something to be implemented), you just have to provide sufficient context for moderators to understand the issue when flagging. This is the way the community has been raising flags when the flags aren't about specific posts for quite some time. Note that if your concern is that mods would reject such flags, rest assured that this is something moderators themselves have also suggested in other answers on Meta.

@LãNgọcHải "but I still think flagging question should be for the question only" - no don't do that. Do things the Stack Overflow way, not your way. You'll have a much better time on this site if you go with the flow and not against it.

@Gimby come on, I didn't mean to do it my way. I don't know what should be done that's why I asked this question

the best thing to do is to flag a post of the reviewer, not an SG post they reviewed. This way moderators can find the relevant flag history from the reviewer's profile.

@LãNgọcHải Fair enough but then I have to wag my finger and say that using phrasing like "I still think", which is like saying "I haven't changed my mind regardless of what you said to me", is exactly how you pull blighters like me out of the woodwork :)
